# Reroute query string using friendlyUrl

Tags: asp.net, webforms, friendly-url

I am trying to rewrite my URLs when I make a search. But I can't even get the segments out of my URL, or maybe there are no segments but then I dont knwo how to change it.

How I try to get segments in `Find.aspx` pageload:

```
IList <string> segments = Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments();
            for (int i = 0; i < segments.Count; i++)
            {
                Label1.Text += "- " + segments[i] + " -"; 
            }
```

This is just to test if it even find 1 segment, which it does not.

I have also tried setting in it my RouteConfig like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

    routes.MapPageRoute("", "Find", "~/Find.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("Find", "Find/{Result}", "~/Find.aspx");
}
```

I want to change the URL from this:

```
www.site.com/Find?Result=Test
```

To this:

```
www.site.com/Find/Test
```

or

```
www.site.com/Test
```

I "call" the link like this `Response.redirect("~/Find.aspx?Result=" + searchString)`

I am also wondering if `Localhost:xxxxx/Default` Means that when I eventually buy a domain my startpage will look like `www.sitename.com/Default`? If so how can I reroute that to be just `www.sitename.com`?

Basically just want to make my site more SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to comment below lines, then it should work.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "Find", "~/Find.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Find", "Find/{Result}", "~/Find.aspx");
```

More info -- [Refer this](https://arindamnayak1.wordpress.com/2015/03/07/seo-friendly-url-routing-in-asp-net/).

#### Purpose of these lines

1. `routes.MapPageRoute("", "FindXXX", "~/Find.aspx");` is to replace `Find.aspx` with FindXXX, here `FindXXX` is SEO friendly name. And it does not send any parameter to `Find.aspx` .

**Usage** - It provides SEO friendly name to `Find.aspx`. To use this, you need  to hit url - `http://localhost:63197/FindXXX`

2. `routes.MapPageRoute("Find", "FindMore/{Result}", "~/Find.aspx");`  -- This line add SEO friendlyness + provides way to pass param to SEO friendly URL.

**Usage** - URL - `http://localhost:63197/FindMore/abc`. To get value  - you need to use following - `Page.RouteData.Values["Result"]`

**Why it was not working** -  In your case, both lines had SEO friendly name as `Find` and that made  confusion to routing engine, and then failed.

#### How worked

Following is the url, I have tried.
[image]

Following is the output,

[image]

And I have commented following.

[image]

Comment: Oooh, So that code somehow messed with FriendlyUrls. So how do I redirect to "Find" now? Before I used `Response.redirect("Find.aspx?Result=" + query)` . What should I replace this line with? My problem is not that I cant get values, I want to replace the `?Result=` with a `/ ` in the URL so that it is SEO

Comment: I think you are trying to explain how I can get values from the URL. I want to make the URL more SEO friendly by removing `?Result=` and replacing it with a `/` . So `www.site.com/Find?Result=query` becomes `www.site.com/Find/query`

Comment: Yes, you are right in last comment, it should be `www.site.com/Find/query`  with code suggested  by me.

Comment: But how? You did not change anything except comment the 2 lines? That does not work for me

Comment: That is the magic of FriendlyURL, just need to have those 3 line and DLL reference, it will make `.aspx` file as SEO friendly, It should work, just clean and rebuild project.

Comment: My URL still looks like this `www.localhost:xxxxx/Find?Result=query`

Comment: I have already mentioned, you need to use `www.localhost:xxxxx/Find/query` with code suggested by me.

Comment: I tried redirecting by using `response.redirect("~/Find/" + query.Text);` But then I dont know how to use `Page.RouteData.Values["Result"]` . I think you are skipping a step or 2 that are obvious to you maybe? But I have no clue, never done rerouting before. If you could show the code for how you actually send the query-parameter with the redirect that would be good.

Comment: @MrCharli3 , forget you code, just follow what is written below `How worked`, it will work. I can not re-iterate the same thing in answer in comment, however  to make it simple i am doing so --> comment last 2 line - hit url like this/ or redirect to `www.localhost:xxxx/Find/query` -- get that query value using - `IList<string> segments = Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments()`

Answer (score 0):

First Of All You have to mapPage Url Like This

```
Routes.MapPageRoute("RouteName", "User/Friendly/Page/Address", "~/OriginalPageAdress.aspx")
```

```
Routes.MatPageRoute("Find", "Find/{result}/", "~/Find.aspx")
 (/) Character must be place in the last of firendlyUrl b'coz if you enter some text with the space(s) then friendlyUrl will not work Properly.
```

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    //Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent("Search", New With {.paramName = "paramValue", ...})
    Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent("Find", New With {.result = "Search Value"})

End Sub
```

To Access "Search Value" enter the following code in "~/Find.aspx" Page :

```
Dim SearchValue as String = Page.RouteData.Values("result")

Response.Write(String.Format("Result For : {0}"), SearchValue)
```

For UrlSegments

```
dim Segm = Request.Urls.Segments(0)
```