# Handle dynamic number of optional URL parameters in IIS rewrite rules

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

My scenario is as follows: a venue can be part of multiple categories and users can also add filters on multiple category types, so my URLs now are like:

1. `/venues/beaches/boats/themeparks` 
   (this will display all venues that are beaches AND boats AND themeparks)
2. `/venues/beaches/boats`
3. `/venues` etc.

So the number of different venue types (beaches, boats, themeparks etc) is both dynamic AND optional. How can I setup my rewrite rules that the `category` querystring parameter holds all the different venue types or preferably the `category` parameter is added multipe times and if no venuetype is provided `category` will just be empty/null?

So for URL: `/venues/beaches/boats/themeparks`

I'd get this rewritten URL: `search.aspx?category=beaches&category=boats&category=themeparks`

And for URL: `/venues`

I'd get this rewritten URL: `search.aspx?category=` (or fine too would be: `search.aspx`)

I now just have this:

```
<rule name="venue types">
  <match url="^venues/([a-zA-Z0-9-+']+)$"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="search.aspx?category={R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

**update**

I went with the below suggestion of @Arindam Nayak.

I installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Core/ and manually created a `RouteConfig.vb` file in `App_Start` folder.  I added (as a test):

```
Public NotInheritable Class RouteConfig
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)
        Dim settings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)

        routes.MapPageRoute("", "test", "~/contact.aspx")

    End Sub
End Class
```

And in `global.aspx.vb` I added:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub
```

When I go to `www.example.com/test`, it does now correctly redirect me to contact.aspx. (Be aware: URL Rewriting - so rules in `web.config` or `rewriteRules.config` file - take precedence over `RouteConfig.vb`!)

I'm almost there, so this `www.example.com/test` redirects correctly to file `contact.aspx`
But this `www.example.com/test/boats/outside/more/fields/are/here`, throws a 404 error:

[image]

**update 2**

I added logging to `routeConfig.vb`:

```
    GlobalFunctions.Log("1")
    Dim settings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
    GlobalFunctions.Log("2")
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
    GlobalFunctions.Log("3")
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)
    GlobalFunctions.Log("4")
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "test", "~/contact.aspx")
    GlobalFunctions.Log("5")
```

And these lines are all executed. Now something strange is happening:
routeConfig.vb seems to only be executed once. So:

1. I build my app.
2. I goto `/test` URL
3. the lines are logged and I arrive on the `contact.aspx` page
4. I refresh the /test page, NO lines are logged

And I also tried:

1. I build my app.
2. I goto `/test/boats/outside/more/fields/are/here` URL
3. the lines are logged
4. I get the aforementioned 404 error
5. I refresh the page, nothing is logged anymore

So it seems routeConfig is only ever hit once (at applicationstart?) and then never hit again. And for request `/test/boats/outside/more/fields/are/here` it arrives at routeConfig.vb file, but does not show `contact.aspx` for some reason...

**update 3**

I found that when I explicitly define the routes, it does work, like so:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "test", "~/contact.aspx")
routes.MapPageRoute("", "test/123", "~/contact.aspx")
```

So now URL `/test` and `/test/123` work, but that is not dynamic at all as I just want to match on `/test` and then get the FriendlyUrlSegments.

I can't post the code online, so if it helps, here's my solution explorer:
[image]

What can I do?

Comment: You can follow my blog on this - https://arindamnayak1.wordpress.com/2015/03/07/seo-friendly-url-routing-in-asp-net/, you can use `Request.GetFriendlyURLSegments`, it will return you array of values, i.e. for `venues/X/Y/Z` it will be `[x,y,z]`, if you need further details, I can post this as an answer.

Comment: @ArindamNayak thanks. Yes, the recommended way of answering on SO is always to answer on SO itself (the external site might be taken down in the future). So yes, I'd love to have your answer here, applied to my scenario :) Thanks again!

Comment: I have posted my suggestion as answer.

Comment: can you try removing `rewriteRules.config` and then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have such kind of SEO friendly URL you need to install “Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls”  nuget package.

Open package manager console – [Help](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console). Then type following –

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls`

Then it will automatically add following in RouteConfig.cs.

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
      var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
      settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
      routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings); 
    }
}
```

For you case, you need to add following to `RouteConfig.cs`.

`routes.MapPageRoute("", "venues", "~/venues.aspx");`

So when you hit url `http://www.example.com/venues/beaches/boats/themeparks` or `http://www.example.com/venues/beaches`, it will hit `venues.aspx`. In `venues.aspx.cs`, `page_load` event you need to have following code.

`IList<String> str = Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments();`

For case-1, str will be `['beaches','boats','themeparks']` and for case-2 it will be `['beaches']`.

For more info you can refer to [my blog](https://arindamnayak1.wordpress.com/2015/03/07/seo-friendly-url-routing-in-asp-net/) or similar SO answer here - [Reroute query string using friendlyUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855430/reroute-query-string-using-friendlyurl/28917163?noredirect=1#28917163)

Let me know,if you face any issue or still your issue is unresolved.

Comment: I'm going through the NuGet Package manager in Visual Studio and see `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls`, but also `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Core` where the description of the latter seems to match my needs more. Which one do I need? And I'm using VB.NET and don't have a RouteConfig file yet...does that matter?

Comment: I would suggest to go with `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls`, if that fails then go with 2nd one. You can go for a simple MVC based project ( a side project), if that works there, then take the components and make it work with existing one.

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost there I think, one final error seems to throw me off...see my updated post. Hope you can help! (ps my apologies for the many post updates)

Comment: @Flo, it should work, can you share your project in github or zip file?

Comment: unfortunately I can't do that...I removed the rewriteRules.config completely now, but still the error persists...I added `update 2` section to my original post...do you have any other debug suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: @Flo, since the code is written in `app_start` , it is executed once. Are you trying to host the application and try or while debugging ( like `localhost:XXXX`), it is not working?

Comment: thanks. I'm running the app on my local machine using the full hostname, so `www.example.com`, I'll try to run it on localhost too, although I don't see (yet) how that would help :)

Comment: @Flo, just because to rule out any server specific setting.

Comment: see my update 3....it does work when explicitly defining the paths...why is it not working on just the url part I define and thus more dynamically? (ps I upvoted your answer, but will assign reward when this last part is solved :))

Comment: @Flo, give me some time, I'll check and will let you know.